# The Return value

Tags: java

I'm a newbie when it comes to Java and I would like to learn how to code, but I am stuck on this question:

What is the returned value?

```
  int s = 2;
  int w = "QCR".hashCode() % 3000;
  int k = "KHF".hashCode() % 3000;
  for (int y = 0; y <= k; y++)
     s = (s ^ y) % w;
  return s;
```

Can someone please help me with this and If you have an answer, can you please explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe run the code? Through a debugger?

Comment: The answer is 1955 :) Try it yourself https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: Do you know what `hashCode()` does? If so then take a piece of paper and a pen and walk through the code. If you don't know what it does look where it's defined and walk through it. Then you will truly start to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 1955, [see on ideone](http://ideone.com/ckBYFe).
If you are having trouble running this code try using online editor like ideone.

Some explanation of what is happening:

```
.hashCode()
```

is bultin method that computes [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function?oldformat=true) value of a given object (string "QCR" in this example).

```
x % 3000
```

computes x [modulo](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Modulo_operation) 3000

```
a ^ b
```

this is a xor b, it's a [bitwise operation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bitwise_operation).

BTW, is hard to say what this code will output just by looking at it, because hash functions are very random (and no one remembers hash value of string "QCR"). 
If you're trying to learn programming test and play with code a lot (but  on your own). If you are having trouble with running or compiling then ask here, but try to put some effort in finding the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I tried figuring out without help and I was completely lost. I'm going to buy some books on Java programming so I can get better and refer here for anymore help. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Sure no problem. From my perspective I can say that learning programming from books is hard. I would start by following some online java tutorial (try googling some) and doing some easy tasks on hackerrank.com or codeforces.com. Later you could try to do some small but interesting projects on your own. Also youtube is your friend in finding good tutorials.

Comment: "because hash functions are very random (and no one remembers hash value of string "QCR")" They're not random, and nobody needs to, because you can simply compute it, either in code, or, if you're feeling particuarly masochistic, using the formula [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()). Since the codepoint values of Q and C and R are 81, 67 and 82 respectively, the hashcode would be 81*31^2 + 67*31 + 82 = 80000.